# why there are three options in the default configure file of redis?

Tags: redis

save configure in `redis.conf` have three options like the following, I am wondering which one of them will be chosen where redis server in running.

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the will be used together once the Redis server runs. The following are lines just above these directives in the [`redis.conf`](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) file:

```
#   In the example below the behaviour will be to save:
#   after 900 sec (15 min) if at least 1 key changed
#   after 300 sec (5 min) if at least 10 keys changed
#   after 60 sec if at least 10000 keys changed
```